# allure plugin "io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm" is throwing VM crashed or system.exit called

Tags: junit4, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin, allure

I am configuring allure reports in my existing automation framework that consist of Java, maven, cucumber and junit.
I've configured it rightly by following allure documentation (https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_cucumber_jvm). But when i am running mvn test , it gives following exception:
The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called...

It is not able to load "-Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm"
Can someone please help me?

PS: It generates the report when i am running tests from feature files, but i need to run it through maven because i have to integrate these results in jenkins pipeline"
Can someone please help me?

Refer to these similar issues:

[The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65182432/16702657)

[Error: Could not find or load main class -Dcucumber.options=--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61489484/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-dcucumber-options-plugin-io-qameta-a)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after doing the following changes:

Remove `"Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm"` from POM.

Actually i was running my tests with the following command:

```
mvn -f pom.xml -s settings.xml test -P package-test -Dmaven.test.skip=false -Dtest.tagnames=XYZ"
```

Package-test contains cucumber runner files that have plugIn already added.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = {"@Regression_TC_01"},
        plugin = {"io.qameta.allure.cucumber4jvm.AllureCucumber4Jvm","pretty", "html:target/html_report/Regression_TC_01/",
                "json:target/cucumber-report/Regression_TC_01.json"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/feature/test.feature"},
        glue = {"com.ek.runcukes.regression"}
```

As per my understanding adding Plugin in Cucumber Runner files and POM were conflicting. Removing it from POM worked for me.